# Change values to text in listbox

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am trying to change the values displayed in a listbox in access 2007, i.e. display "0" as "No".  The table I am querying is a linked table on a mysql server.  What I have,

```
issue_string = "SELECT IF(Issues.issue_closed = 0, 'no', 'yes') FROM Issues;"
Me.lbx_Issue_List.RowSource = issue_string
Me.lbx_Issue_List.Requery
```

If I try running the statement on it's own it dies with "undefined function 'IF' in expression.

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(issue_string)
```

The statement is perfectly valid when run on the mysql server, so how do I get access to actually pass the statement?  Is there another way to get this functionality out of the listbox?

Comment: at what line the error occurs?